# Indefinite integral of quotient of polynomials

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I cannot find a way to integrate this,
$$\int\frac{2x^6-13x^5+23x^4-15x^3+40x^2-24x+9}{x^5-6x^4+9x^2}dx$$

I searched for a solution on WolframAlpha but the answer is in terms of <s>complex</s> complex-valued functions.
So the question is, how can I prove that it is not possible to compute this indefinite integral in terms of *<s>simple</s> elementary real-valued functions*?

Comment: By simple functions, do you mean *elementary functions?* I.e. polynomials and transcendentals?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by simple and complex. The issue is that your integrand is equal to

$$\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{59 x^2 - 150 x + 165}{3 (x^3 - 6 x^2 + 9)} + 2 x - \frac{8}{3 x} - 1$$

The second can be integrated, just not easily. I believe Wolfram decomposed the denominator in terms of its roots, did a partial fraction decomposition, and integrated the results -- the issue being cubics often don't have nice roots [(see here)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9+-+6+x%5E2+%2B+x%5E3+%3D+0). They are at least real-valued though, despite the abundance of $i$'s in the expressions.

Comment: You can still factorize once more the cubic polynomial (every cubic polynomial has a real root) and then you can develop the rational fraction into a sum of rational fractions with only order 1 or 2 polynomials as denominators.

Comment: Right, I meant elementary functions and complex-valued functions.

Comment: You should check your sources. Likely that the intended denominator was $x^6 - 6 x^4 + 9 x^2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

A key issue is to factor the denominator in a manageable form.

We solve

$$x^3-6x^2+9=0$$ by setting

$$x=\frac3{\sqrt8z}$$

and after simplification,

$$4z^3-3z=-\frac3{4\sqrt{2}}.$$

Hence the three real roots are

$$\frac3{\sqrt8\cos\left(\dfrac13{\arccos\left(-\dfrac{3}{4\sqrt2}\right)}\right)},\\\frac3{\sqrt8\cos\left(\dfrac13{\arccos\left(-\dfrac{3}{4\sqrt2}\right)}+\dfrac{2\pi}3\right)},\\\frac3{\sqrt8\cos\left(\dfrac13{\arccos\left(-\dfrac{3}{4\sqrt2}\right)}+\dfrac{4\pi}3\right)}.$$

Now you can decompose in simple fractions. You can start from the form given by @EeveeTrainer and

$$\frac{59x^2-150x+165}{x^3-6x^2+9}=\frac a{x-x_0}+\frac b{x-x_1}+\frac c{x-x_2}$$ is easy to integrate.

Comment: I've suggested that the denominator was intended to be $x^6 - 6 x^4 + 9 x^2.$

Comment: @WillJagy: this is likely. But handling the cubic was more fun. :-)

Comment: You have a good attitude.